# Starting rowspan and colspan from a given cell and reduce padding of rowspan

Tags: html, css

I am writing a PHP script that is dynamically creating a HTML table.

There are two things that are missing and cannot find info on.

I'd like to reduce the "padding" of the rowspan cell, it is much too large horizontally. What can you use to modify the spacing between the string inside and the end of the cell?

I would also like to start the rowspan from the 3 row up to the last one, and start the colspan from column 3 up to the last one. Can this be done?

HTML source code if you wish to see what the table looks like:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="17">Weight, in Kg</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="11">Height, in cm</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>40</th>
    <th>45</th>
    <th>50</th>
    <th>55</th>
    <th>60</th>
    <th>65</th>
    <th>70</th>
    <th>75</th>
    <th>80</th>
    <th>85</th>
    <th>90</th>
    <th>95</th>
    <th>100</th>
    <th>105</th>
    <th>110</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>160</th>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>165</th>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>170</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>175</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>180</th>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>185</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>190</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>195</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>200</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 2x2 *"filler"* cell. Then start the column label cell one `<tr>` later. You basically have two header rows running horizontally, hence starting the vertical header row in the third `<tr>`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>
    <th colspan="17">Weight, in Kg</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>40</th>
    <th>45</th>
    <th>50</th>
    <th>55</th>
    <th>60</th>
    <th>65</th>
    <th>70</th>
    <th>75</th>
    <th>80</th>
    <th>85</th>
    <th>90</th>
    <th>95</th>
    <th>100</th>
    <th>105</th>
    <th>110</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="11">Height, in cm</th>
    <th>160</th>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>165</th>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>170</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>175</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>180</th>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>185</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>190</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>195</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>200</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you say *"padding"* I'm understanding it as the white space on either side of **Wight, in Kg** to the border of the cell. If that's the case:

1. Increase the font size, which might look ugly.
2. Increase [letter spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing), `letter-spacing: 0.25em;`, which might look ugly.

If you're talking about the white space after the numbers in the **100**, **105** and **110** columns you can do above but I'd suggest having all the columns be the same width and then centering all the numbers to even everything out.

Note that there's less white space for triple digits than double digits with this approach.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
th,
td {
  min-width: 1.85rem;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>
    <th colspan="17">Weight, in Kg</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>40</th>
    <th>45</th>
    <th>50</th>
    <th>55</th>
    <th>60</th>
    <th>65</th>
    <th>70</th>
    <th>75</th>
    <th>80</th>
    <th>85</th>
    <th>90</th>
    <th>95</th>
    <th>100</th>
    <th>105</th>
    <th>110</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="11">Height, in cm</th>
    <th>160</th>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>165</th>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>170</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>175</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>180</th>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>185</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>190</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>195</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>200</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could set a specific amount of padding on columns and center. I personally like the result of the code snippet above. Here you get consistent white space around then numbers while sacrificing equal column width.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 0.125rem 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>
    <th colspan="17">Weight, in Kg</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>40</th>
    <th>45</th>
    <th>50</th>
    <th>55</th>
    <th>60</th>
    <th>65</th>
    <th>70</th>
    <th>75</th>
    <th>80</th>
    <th>85</th>
    <th>90</th>
    <th>95</th>
    <th>100</th>
    <th>105</th>
    <th>110</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="11">Height, in cm</th>
    <th>160</th>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>165</th>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>170</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>175</th>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>180</th>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>185</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>190</th>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>195</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>200</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If neither of those are what you're referencing, please clarify.